# .htaccess redirect from dir with params to sub domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have basically moved some billing software from domain.co.uk/billing/ to billing.domain.co.uk

I basically need a htaccess rewrite rule to redirect everything

**from**

```
  domain.co.uk/billing/invoice?=1
```

**to**

```
  billing.domain.co.uk/invoice?=1
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so with [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
Redirect 301 /billing http://billing.billing.domain.co.uk
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must keep http://domain.co.uk hosted somewhere. Inside it you have the billing folder.

Inside billing folder you have htaccess with this code:

< IfModule mod_rewrite.c >

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/invoice?=(.*)$ http://billing.domain.co.uk/invoice?=$2 [R=301,L]
```

< /IfModule >